# ZF2 select not shows any results

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, select, zend-framework

I'm trying show a query result in Zend Framework using Zend Debug in the Controller. But the only thing that the "select" method in the Model returns is a object like this (only with the number of results, but without de data results):

```
object(Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet)#303 (8) {
["allowedReturnTypes":protected] => array(2) {
[0] => string(11) "arrayobject"
[1] => string(5) "array"
}
["arrayObjectPrototype":protected] => object(Grupos\Model\CategoriaGrupo)#288 (6) {
["id"] => NULL
["titulo"] => NULL
["img"] => NULL
["alt"] => NULL
["slug"] => NULL
["ativo"] => NULL
}
["returnType":protected] => string(11) "arrayobject"
["buffer":protected] => NULL
["count":protected] => int(17)
["dataSource":protected] => object(Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result)#302 (8) {
["statementMode":protected] => string(7) "forward"
["resource":protected] => object(PDOStatement)#294 (1) {
["queryString"] => string(49) "SELECT `grupo_categoria`.* FROM `grupo_categoria`"
}
["options":protected] => NULL
["currentComplete":protected] => bool(false)
["currentData":protected] => NULL
["position":protected] => int(-1)
["generatedValue":protected] => string(1) "0"
["rowCount":protected] => int(17)
}

["fieldCount":protected] => int(6)
["position":protected] => int(0)
}
```

How you can see, don't shows the results, only the number of rows founded: 17.

All the other queries works perfectly. All it's right with the table database and with the database permissions. I will put here the Model.php, the two models and the controller to show you:

**Module.php**

```
...    
public function getServiceConfig()
    {
            return array(
                'factories' => array(
                    'Grupos\Model\CategoriaGrupoTable' => function ($sm) {
                        $tableGateway = $sm->get('CategoriaGrupoTableGateway');
                        $table = new CategoriaGrupoTable($tableGateway);
                        return $table;
                    },
                    'CategoriaGrupoTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                        $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new CategoriaGrupo());
                        return new TableGateway('grupo_categoria', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                    }
                )
            );
        }
```

**GruposController.php**

```
class GruposController extends AbstractActionController
{

protected $categoriaGrupoTable;

public function getCategoriaGrupoTable()
    {
        if (! $this->categoriaGrupoTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->categoriaGrupoTable = $sm->get('Grupos\Model\CategoriaGrupoTable');
        }
        return $this->categoriaGrupoTable;
    }

public function categoriasAction()
    {
        // Define as configurações e conteúdos das páginas
        $tituloPagina = $translator->translate("Editar Grupo");

        $categorias = $this->getCategoriaGrupoTable()->listar();

        Debug::dump($categorias);

        die();
}
}
```

**Model -> CategoriaGrupoTable.php**

```
<?php
namespace Grupos\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class CategoriaGrupoTable
{

    protected $tableGateway;

    function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    /**
     * Método que lista todas as categorias ativas
     *
     * @return \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet
     */
    public function listar()
    {
        return $this->tableGateway->select();
    }
}

?>
```

**Model -> CategoriaGrupo.php**

```
<?php
namespace Grupos\Model;

class CategoriaGrupo
{

    public $id;

    public $titulo;

    public $img;

    public $alt;

    public $slug;

    public $ativo;

    // Método que popula o objeto com dados vindos de uma array
    public function exchangeArray($dados)
    {
        $this->id = (! empty($dados["id"])) ? $dados["id"] : null;
        $this->titulo = (! empty($dados["titulo"])) ? $dados["titulo"] : "";
        $this->img = (! empty($dados["img"])) ? $dados["img"] : "";
        $this->alt = (! empty($dados["alt"])) ? $dados["alt"] : "";
        $this->slug = (! empty($dados["slug"])) ? $dados["slug"] : "";
        $this->titulo = (! empty($dados["ativo"])) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    // Esse método pegar o Objeto (que é a própria classe) e retornará ele como se fosse um array
    public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}

?>
```

Well.. this is the problem and voilà the sources files... If someone can give-me a light, i will be so grateful! I'm sorry for my english. I'm trying does 2 weeks found the error. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the time and help. I found the problem: in the form I decelerated two time "titulo" in exchangeArray method. And this cause that my entire data of the table comes with null or empty, with exception of the slug... Thank yo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the time and help. I found the problem: in the form I decelerated two time "titulo" in exchangeArray method. And this cause that my entire data of the table comes with null or empty, with exception of the slug... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you read the documentation of zend framewrok 2 to get a better understanding of how queries work.

Now for the solution. Under

Model -> CategoriaGrupoTable.php modify the listar() function

```
 public function listar()
    {
        $result =  $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $result->toArray();
    }
```

Comment: Hello dixromo98, thank you for your answer. I know this and I tried this. But the result is all de queries but only with the data for the "slug" table column. All the others columns returns incorrect or empty values. See a exempla: 

array(17) {
  [0] => array(6) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "1"
    ["titulo"] => int(1)
    ["img"] => string(0) ""
    ["alt"] => string(0) ""
    ["slug"] => string(7) "estudos"
    ["ativo"] => NULL
  }
But all the records in Database have data... Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Otherwise, appears this error to: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Zend\Db\Sql\Sql could not be converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Gruppe/module/Grupos/src/Grupos/Model/CategoriaGrupoTable.php on line 24. That is the line "return $result->toArray();